# Ionic 4 check button show multiple select values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to show the list with select options so i use check button. But the problem is i can select multiple values and i need to show all selected values it in console here is my code

```
<ion-list (ionChange)="checkValue($event)">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let usr of usersList"  >
      <ion-label>{{usr.username}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox slot="start" value={{usr.userId}} ></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

.ts

```
 checkValue(event){
   console.log(event.detail.value);
 }
```

The problem in code is it can not select multiple values and i need to show like array in console.

Comment: You understand radio buttons are generally used for single selections right? You'd be better off using checkboxes if you want to be able to select many options. Ion-radio-group: "A radio group is a group of radio buttons. It allows a user to select at most one radio button from a set"

Comment: thanks i can select multiple values now. but hove can i get values in array ? mean its stilel showing one selected value

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain an array in the background that the selected items are added to and deselected ones removed from. This will work to add the items:

```
selectedItems: any;

checkValues(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.value);
    if(!this.selectedItems) this.selectedItems = new Array();

    this.selectedItems.push(event.detail.value);
}
```

To also remove an item when it is unselected, loop through the selectedItems array looking for a match (using filter or a for loop) and splice out the value if it is found.

Comment: If you don't like to use `any`, set the variable as the corrected type (if your return value is a string) and init an empty array `selectedItems: string[] = []` and you can remove the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can you ion-select instead of checkbox

this below is checked and works for me

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Hair Color</ion-label>
    <ion-select
      value="brown"
      multiple
      ok-text="Okay"
      cancel-text="Dismiss"
      (ionBlur)="selectedItems($event)"
    >
      <ion-select-option value="brown">Brown</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="blonde">Blonde</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="black">Black</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="red">Red</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

in ts file

```
  selectedItems(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
```